# Creating a visual studio menu command that accepts parameters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create a menu command that takes a single parameter. I created a new VSIX Project w/ Command (Community). The command works, but when I try to pass in a parameter through the command window I receive an error that this command doesn't accept params or switches. I've changed the command flag from IconIsMoniker to AllowParams in the vsct file. I am not sure what else would be required.

My command

I would expect the command to take the parameter. Instead it returns "Command "GitWorktreeExtension.MyCommand" does not accept arguments or switches."

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set ParametersDescription to "$" for your OleMenuCommand.

Full example: https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/CommandWithArguments